# Variable lookup parameter for resourceBundle?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-webflow, resourcebundle

I'm currently using the resourceBundle variable to get text values in my JSF code e.g. like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{resourceBundle.welcomeMessage}" />
```

Is there any way, to put the message key in a variable, and give it as a dynamic parameter to the resource bundle? I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
<c:set var="name" value="#{'welcomeMessage'}" />
<h:outputText value="#{resourceBundle.get(name)}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource bundle takes dynamic parameter. Here is snippet from my project:

```
    <f:loadBundle basename="#{siteName}" var="bundle"/>
        ....
               <h:dataTable value="#{summary.restrictionList}" var="restrictionList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
               ....

                            <h:outputFormat value="#{bundle['summary.label.blockcodemsg']}">
                                <f:param value="#{restrictionList['lastFourDigits']}"/>
                                <f:param value="#{bundle[restrictionList['optionDesc']]}"/>
                                <f:param value="#{bundle[restrictionList['optionResolutionDesc']]}"/>
                            </h:outputFormat>
     ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a dedicated ManagedBean  with a method `resolveKey(String key)` from which call resourceBundle lookup and on view and use that bean.

Answer (score 1):

Use [h:outputFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/outputFormat.html), see example: http://www.javabeat.net/tips/47-how-to-use-resource-bundle-in-jsf.html